# android:Get photo from facebook post using graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Graph API in my android app to get posts of a facebook page.The result is JSONObject.

Posts are of 3 types - status, link, photo

For a post of type **photo** contains a picture which is available in the page album.

1. I'm loading this image from the **picture** field(typically a web URL) in the response json object. However the image is of poor quality.
2. To get the original picture, I should get it from the album/photos of the page.

**Problem**: The problem in the second case is, How do I get the id for that picture from the post? to query it from the album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is in the field object_id in the json.

You have to make an additional call with this ID then.

Comment: oh yeah!, you are correct, I found it myself couple of days back itself and forgot to update here. Anyhow accepting your answer for spending your time on this.

Comment: Hi Frank- Can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/25098320/3786487