# GRAPH API:how to get hyperlinks from a post

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

It is usual to have hyperlinks in the facebook post.
**For ex:** I may post something like this "Yesterday I went to  restaurant".

Now in the above example, By clicking the restaurant name it redirects to facebook page of the restaurant.

**Requirement:**
I am using GRAPH API on android to get the post content,mostly **"message"** field is the content, **but it contains only text.**

How to get the details of hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the answer myself:**

The hyperlink details are present in the message_tag field.

ex:

```
message_tag:
       id:<id of the fb page/account>
       name:<name of the account>
       offset:120
       length:20
```

Here the hyperlink would be from 120 position to 140 of the text in the message field.